# I want to pass questions in a data frame into the OpenAI API model but I keep getting none as an output

Tags: python, pandas, openai-api

I am currently having a go at the open AI API, I want to be able to pass a pandas dataframe which has multiple questions into the model and get responses for each question.

```
class Test(mlflow.pyfunc.PythonModel):
    def model_test(self, input_query):
        prompt = [input_query]
        try:
            response = openai.Completion.create(
                engine="ada",
                prompt=prompt,
                temperature=0.6,
                max_tokens=30,
            )
            text = response['choices'][0]['text']
            return text
        except Exception as ex:
            print(str(ex))
            return None

    def predict(self, context, df):
        if not isinstance(df, pd.core.frame.DataFrame):
            raise ValueError("Input to predict is not a dataframe")
```

I have written the class above, and I want the input to be similar to the below, but I keep getting the response 'None'.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Questions': ['What is the capital of the USA?']})
magic = Test()
response = magic.predict(None, df)
print(response)
```

Anyone have any idea where I am going wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Your predict method has no return. So when you assign ```response = magic.predict(None, df)``` response is assigned with None.